# AngularJS hide promises while using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-promise

I have a simple RESTful service like the following:

```
services.factory('UserService', ['$resource, function() {
   return $resource('...');
}]);
```

This way I have to invoke like this:

```
UserService.get({id: userId}, function(response) {
 // do something.
});
```

I wanted to be able to do something like this:

```
UserService.get(userId).then(function(response) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Is it possible? I am struggling with this and end up always having to use $promise.then() in my controllers. I wanted to "hide" that $promise in my RESTful service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource` purposely exposes the promise through ... well ... `$promise`, so you can use the `UserService` to abstract this:

```
services.factory("UserService", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    var userService = $resource("...");

    return {
        get: function (id) {
            return userService.get({id: id}).$promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will do the job. Is this a good practice? How do you use to handle $resource service calls in your controllers?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I tend to prefer `$http` over `$resource` unless the request is *very* simple (i.e. something `$resource` can handle without changing very much).  The methods that *need* to have a callback like `$get` already have a callback argument that you can use.  The `$promise` is just there in case you need it.

Comment: And when using `$http`, in your controllers you end up doing something like: `UsersService.get(userId).success(function(response) {...});` ?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues generally yes.  I tend not to use `$http` in controllers since it makes more sense in services most of the time, but I will return the promise and the controller can chain to that

Answer (score 0):

According to [Todd Motto](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/) you could encapsulate your service somewhat like this :

> "We create an Object with the same name inside the function. This can aid documentation as well for comment-generated docs."

```
function AnotherService () {

    var AnotherService = {};

    AnotherService.someValue = '';

    AnotherService.someMethod = function (idParam) {
        return $resource(apiUrl + ":action/:id", {}, {
            get: {method: 'GET', params: {id:idParam, action: 'get'}
    };

    return AnotherService;

}

angular.module('app')
    .factory('AnotherService', AnotherService);
```